# Calling managed C++ lib from C# passing values by reference

Tags: c#, c++, managed-c++

I'm trying to set up a test project to figure out how to correctly wrap a native C++ lib in a managed C++ DLL, to then be called by a C# application.

For my test case I have 3 application:

**CPP lib**

I compile a library with a class containing four functions.

1) return a double value

2) return a string

3) take a double by reference, modify it.

4) take a string by reference, modify it.

cpp_lib.h

```
namespace cpp_lib
{
   class CPPLibFunctions{

   public:
      CPPLibFunctions();
   public:
      static double getValue();
      static void incrementValue(double& val);

      static std::string getText();
      static void changeText(std::string& txt);
   };
}
```

cpp_lib.cpp

```
#include "cpp_lib.h"
#include <stdexcept>

namespace cpp_lib{
   CPPLibFunctions::CPPLibFunctions(){};

   double CPPLibFunctions::getValue(){
      return 5.5;
   }
   void CPPLibFunctions::incrementValue(double& val){
      val += 1.0;      
   }
   std::string CPPLibFunctions::getText(){
      return "success";
   }
   void CPPLibFunctions::changeText(std::string& txt){
      txt += "_123";
   }
}
```

**Managed CPP lib**

This is a managed C++ project compiled to a DLL, which wraps the functions from cpp_lib.

managed_cpp_lib.h

```
#include "cpp_lib.h"
#pragma once    
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

using namespace System;

namespace managed_cpp_lib {

   System::String^ stdToSysString(std::string str){
      return gcnew System::String(str.c_str());
   }

    public ref class ManagedCppFunctions
    {
   private:
      cpp_lib::CPPLibFunctions * cppLibFunctions;
   public:
      ManagedCppFunctions(){
         cppLibFunctions = new cpp_lib::CPPLibFunctions();
      }

      double getValue(){         
         return  cppLibFunctions->getValue();
      }
      void incrementValue(double& val){
         cppLibFunctions->incrementValue(val);
      }
      System::String^ getText(){
         return stdToSysString(cppLibFunctions->getText());
      }
      void changeText(System::String^ txt){
         //this does not work:
         std::string txtstd = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(txt);
         cppLibFunctions->changeText(txtstd);
         txt = stdToSysString(txtstd);
      }
    };
}
```

**csharp_app**

Lastly, cssharp_app is a C# console application, which references managed_cpp_lib, and calls the functions.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using managed_cpp_lib;

namespace csharp_app
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            managed_cpp_lib.ManagedCppFunctions managedCppFunctions = new managed_cpp_lib.ManagedCppFunctions();

            //works:
            double val = managedCppFunctions.getValue();
            Console.WriteLine("\managedCppFunctions.getValue() = {0}", val);

            //works:
            string txt = managedCppFunctions.getText();
            Console.WriteLine("\managedCppFunctions.getText() = {0}", txt);

            //does not work:
            /*managedCppFunctions.incrementValue(val);
            Console.WriteLine("\managedCppFunctions.incrementValue(val) = {0}", val);*/

            //the string is not modified:
            managedCppFunctions.changeText(txt);
            Console.WriteLine("\managedCppFunctions.changeText(txt) = {0}", txt);

            Console.WriteLine("...");
        }
    }
}
```

The output of **csharp_app** is:

```
managedCppFunctions.getValue() = 5.5
managedCppFunctions.getText() = success
managedCppFunctions.changeText(txt) = success
```

So `managedCppFunctions.getValue()` and `managedCppFunctions.getText()` works.

`managedCppFunctions.changeText(txt)` does not modify the content of the string.

I'm not sure how to implement `managedCppFunctions.incrementValue(val)`.

What is the correct way to pass a double and a string by reference, to then change their values using managed C++ and C#?

Comment: If you want to change a string, pass a `StringBuilder` instead of a `string` - the marshaller will handle this for you. To change a value type, you must declare the parameter as `ref`: `void incrementValue(ref double val)`

Comment: I get `ref is undefined` if I do `void incrementValue(ref double val)` in managed_cpp_lib...

Comment: I meant in the C# code. I think you'll need to put `void incrementValue(double& val)` in the C++.

Comment: Hmm.. That functions is not defined in the C# code. It's defined in the C++ lib, then wrapped in the managed C++ code, which is called by the C# code.

Comment: I can see a `void incrementValue(double val)` in your managed C++ code. That needs to change to `void incrementValue(double& val)`

Comment: That is true. I must have accidentally removed it while testing. I edited the code.

The error I get then in managed cpp is : `The best overloaded method match for managed_cpp_lib.ManagedCppFunctions.incrementValue(double*) has some invalid arguments`

Comment: Hmm, I've no idea why you're getting that error - is the header file correct? Anyway, to change a double passed as a parameter it will have to be either `double&` or `double*`.

Comment: I managed now to make the double by reference work. In the managed cpp I tried with two functions: `void incrementValue(double& val)` and `void incrementValuePtr(double* val)`. They can both be called with `managedCppFunctions.incrementValue(&val)` and `managedCppFunctions.incrementValuePtr(&val)`, if I put them in `unsafe` context.


But I'm still not sure how to work with `String` by reference or `StringBuilder`

Comment: It should work similarly to the Windows API GetWindowText() - [here's the PInvoke.net page for it](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowText.html).